# What is the best way to inquire about a position in a different department?

Tags: internal-transfer

I have been employed at a college research center for 3 years, and my supervisor is an instructor. Today my supervisor informed me that the research funding will be cut this summer which will result in layoffs.

The instructor informed me that a grant writer recently left the college, leaving the position open and that I should speak with the college's senior administrative coordinator. I don't know anything about this position, so what should I say in the email to my contact person? What questions should I ask her?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> Hello x
>
> My instructor, Mr Y has informed me of Mr Z's departure from the role of Grant Writer and has asked me to contact you regarding me being a potentially suitable replacement.
>
> Would it be possible for you to tell me more about this role (duties, hours, etc.), and let me know who to approach regarding an application?
>
> Many thanks,
>
> user342478

Something along those lines.